# Is it possible to catch response in a React website which is opening via redirect from another website?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, redirect

Consider the scenario where I have created a site in Django(website A) and another site in React(website B). I have a button on website A which redirects to website B. While redirecting I am setting up some headers which I want to retrieve from website B when it gets redirected. Is this situation plausible?

Comment: Not from the client code (React), but you could retrieve those headers on a server that serves website B (React) and then ask that server for this information.

Comment: I ended using cookies to share information between the two sites.